# How to Pass parameter to a Command in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, binding, windows-store-apps

View: `<Button Command="{Binding GetChangeLogCommand}"`

ViewModel:  `GetChangeLogCommand = new DelegateCommand(GetChangeLog);`

Method:

```
public ICommand GetChangeLogCommand { get; set; }
private async void GetChangeLog(bool isLatest)
{
    // code goes here . . .
}
```

I'm going to use`GetChangeLogCommand` multiple time and pass boolean parameter is it possible with MVVM sorry I'm new with this.

Comment: you have to use ViewModel binding for that i guess

Comment: and also see this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32064308/how-to-pass-command-parameter-to-method-in-viewmodel-in-wpf

Comment: At your `Button` you can also bind a property called `CommandParameter`. This value will be passed to your command-handler

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data between the View and the ViewModel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036466/how-to-pass-data-between-the-view-and-the-viewmodel)

Answer (score 0):

If you are that particular to pass the button element to viewmodel You can use below code :

```
 CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=YourButtonName}"
```

You could even pass the entire window, user control, or a particular list or list item to the view model

```
 CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=YourWindow}"     
 CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Control}"
```